# Change InlineShape (image) shadow color

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins

I am developing a Word AddIn and want to set the shadow color of an image with C#. The shadow remains black and I do not know how to change the shadow color.

My code:

```
ShadowFormat shadow = Range.InlineShape[1].Shadow;

shadow.ForeColor.RGB = Color.FromArgb(230, 50, 15).ToArgb(); // not working !!
shadow.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShadowType.msoShadow9;
shadow.Style = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShadowStyle.msoShadowStyleOuterShadow;
shadow.Transparency = 0.0f;
```

Does anybody know how to change the shadow color?

Comment: I just tried with VBA and it works for me. I did not use `FromArgb` though but the `WdColor` enumeration, e.g. `inl.Shadow.ForeColor = WdColor.wdColorBrightGreen` - that worked just fine.

Comment: but `ForeColor` is read only

Comment: I see. OK, try this then: `.Shadow.ForeColor.SetCMYK(0,78,93,10);`
These CMYK values correspond to your RGB, courtesy of https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.html

Comment: I tried but got `System.NotImplementedException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interop seems to be rather tricky on this side. Both `set_Ink` and `SetCMYK` throw NotImplementedException.

I found that this works though:

```
shadow.ForeColor.RGB = Word.XlRgbColor.xlAquamarine.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me. I have still just a black shadow.

Comment: Move it to after `MsoShadowType` then. Best: move it to the end of your shadow manipulation. My shadow color did change just fine.